# cv2.polylines gives wrong shape

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I try to draw a reversed triangle with the code below,but it gives a normal triangle, even though the points I give are these of a reversed triangle! Could anybody tell me what I do wrong?

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

f=cv2.imread("C:\Desktop\image.jpg")

pts = np.array([[195,327],[378,327],[286,144]])

pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))

cv2.polylines(f,np.int32([pts]),True,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.namedWindow('img')

cv2.imshow('img', f)

cv2.waitKey()

cv2.destroyWindow('img')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please note the edits I made to your post, and do thusly in the future :)

Comment: Already noted, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OpenCV the coordinates start from the top-left, so (0,0) is the top-left pixel on the view.

Try `pts = np.array([[195,327],[378,327],[286,500]])`